# Why does a car continue to accelerate after letting off the gas pedal?

Tags: acceleration

When I accelerate in my sportscar (ok, its just a Toyota corolla, but it still works), I notice that when I get up to, say 30 mph, and I immediately let off the gas and/or shift into neutral (i.e., in preparation for shifting), the speedometer continues to rise briefly (even when the gas pedal is not pressed and the car is in neutral).  What accounts for this phenomenon?

Comment: I've driven a stick-shift all of my adult life but I've never seen that sort of behavior, nor would I expect to since I think that the speedometer of a car is normally directly linked to the wheels of the car through a cable. It's not unusual for the tachometer to show a brief surge in rpms when shifting gears, though, because the engine is momentarily disengaged from the load of the drive train during shifting.

Comment: The key question: can you still *feel* it accelerating, or just *see the speedometer* increasing?  If the latter, I agree with BowlofRed.  If the former, it might be the car electronics automating for some reason, deliberate or otherwise (you said it was a Toyota, right??)

Answer (score 3):

When the car is in neutral, it's not going to accelerate unless you're pointed downhill.

There are different ways of constructing a speedometer.  Some of them will average over a larger time period to reduce the jumpiness.  This introduces lag into the instrument.  You may be seeing this measurement error.

Consumer GPS units tend to have a bit of lag as well.  You can purchase accelerometers for cars that have high precision, but that may be a bit expensive.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I think what you're saying is that under acceleration (especially hard acceleration) the speedometer is not accurate (the car is going faster than it reads).  If that is the case, then if I let off the gas when the dial reads 30 mph and the dial continues upward until plateauing at 40 mph, that at the moment I let off the gas I was actually going 40 mph (or more).  Is that right?

Comment: 30 to 40 is extreme, I've never sensed or seen that, but Imhate Toyotas. Ifi T actually accelerated 10 mph when you let the gas pedal go it would be a serious safety issue, electronics or not. Careful with self driving cars.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably an artifact of the car's gas-pedal-to-speedometer system (whether it's electronics, mechanical, or both ... I don't know cars that well).

However, physically, in a "perfect world," once you let off the gas your car will stop accelerating. In a perfect world without friction your car would be stuck in the last speed you were at forever -- 30 mph.

In the real world friction from the road will slow your car down. It should slow down at a constant speed (and zero acceleration). If you apply the brakes then you will get negative acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

In an idealized world, the instant one stops supplying fuel, acceleration should stop and deceleration begin. However, in the real world, acceleration may not stop instantly but quickly begin to slow down. Velocity might thus increase slightly at a slower rate.

An engine spinning at 5,000 RPM when fuel was cut off might take a few tenths of a second to return to idle. During the RPM slow down, the angular momentum associated with the engine’s moving mass may continue to supply a decreasing but positive force supporting a reducing acceleration until idle is reached. The impact would vary depending upon speed, wind and rolling resistance, and gearing but could last for 1-3/10th of a second conceivably.